# Why Hibernate is not performing the JOIN on this MANY TO MANY association table using @ManyToMany and @JoinTable annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate mapping and I have the following problem.

I have this **network** table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.network
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT network_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and this **chain** table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.chain
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    fk_chain_type bigint NOT NULL,
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT chain_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "chain_to_chain_type_FK" FOREIGN KEY (fk_chain_type)
        REFERENCES public.chain_type (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID
)
```

These 2 tables are related to each other by a **MANY TO MANY** relationship, implmemented by this **network_chain** table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.network_chain
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    fk_network_id bigint NOT NULL,
    fk_chain_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT network_chain_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT chain_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (fk_chain_id)
        REFERENCES public.chain (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT network_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (fk_network_id)
        REFERENCES public.network (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID
)
```

Basically the **fk_network_id** field represents the id of a specific record into the  **network** table while the **fk_chain_id** represents the id of a specific record into the **chain** table.

I mapped these DB tables with the following Hibernate entity classes, first of all I created this **Network** class mapping the **network** table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "network")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Network implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5341425320975462596L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "network_chain", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_network_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_chain_id") }
    )
    Set<Chain> chainList;

}
```

As you can see it contains the **@ManyToMany** annotation using the **@JoinTable** annotation in order to join my **network** table with  my **chain** table (mapped by the **Chain** entity class) using the previous **network_chain** table (implementing the MANY TO MANY relationship).

So in this **@JoinTable** annotation I am specifying:

- The merging table implementing the MANY TO MANY relationship: **network_chain**.
- the two FK on this table that are **fk_network_id** and **fk_chain_id**.

Then I have this Spring Data JPA repository class named **NetworkRepository**:

```
public interface NetworkRepository extends JpaRepository<Network, Integer> {
    
    /**
     * Retrieve a Network object by its ID
     * @param id of the network
     * @return the retrieve Network object
     */
    Network findById(String id);
    
    /**
     * Retrieve a Network object by its name
     * @param name of the network
     * @return a Network object
     */
    Network findByName(String name);
    
    /**
     * Retrieve the list of all the possible networks
     * @return a List<Network> object: the list of the all the networks
     */
    List<Network> findAll();

}
```

Finally I created a JUnit test class containing a method in order to test the previous repository **findAll()** method, this one:

```
@SpringBootTest()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GetUserWsApplication.class)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class NetworkTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private NetworkRepository networkRepository;
    
    /**
     * Retrieve the networks list
     */
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void findAllTest() {
        
        List<Network> networksList = this.networkRepository.findAll();
        
        assertTrue(networksList.size() == 5, "It retrieved 5 networks");
        
        Set<Chain> networkChain = networksList.get(0).getChainList();
        
        assertTrue(networkChain != null, "The network chains list are not null");
    }

}
```

The problem is that the **findAll()** method  execute this SQL statement( I can see it into my stacktrace):

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        network0_.id as id1_6_,
        network0_.description as descript2_6_,
        network0_.name as name3_6_ 
    from
        network network0_
```

and retrieve the expected **List** object but as you can see in the following printscreen my **chainList** field give an error:

[image]

It seems that it have not retrieved the chainList from my **MANY TO MANY** table (infact thre previous Hibernate statement seems not perform any join on the **network_chain** and then **chain** tables).

I also tried to directly access to this field by this line (my idea was that maybe Hibernate performed this join when the access to this field is explicitly performed:

```
Set<Chain> networkChain = networksList.get(0).getChainList();
```

It seems that this **com.sun.jdi.InvocationException** exceptions happens when I try to retrieve this field. Basically it seems that the JOINS between the **MANY TO MANY** table and the on the **chain** table is never performed.

Why? What is wrong with my code? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have an extra column (`id`) in the table (`network_chain`) which is responsible for the `many-to-many` relationship.

The `@JoinTable` annotation will support the definition of only 2 fields, usually the `id`s of the 2 tables. The 2 `id`s together, will be the `primary key` for the join table, also known as a `composite primary key`.

In your case, you will have to create an entity to represent the table `network_chain`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "network_chain")
public class NetworkChain {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToOne
   private Network network;
   
   @ManyToOne
   private Chain chain;    
}

public class Network implements Serializable {
    //somewhere in the code
    @OneToMany
    List<NetworkChain> networkChains;
}

public class Chain implements Serializable {
    //somewhere in the code
    @OneToMany
    List<NetworkChain> networkChains;
}
```

Now, the entity `NetworkChain` has the extra column `id` as the primary key and hibernate will do the proper joins to fetch the data.

**Out of topic** but not sure why there is a javadoc for the `findAll()` method which is usually part of the `JpaRepository` and weird `findById` as well..